# Werbrtc2sip crashing intermittently. Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: asterisk, voip, sip, rtp

I am having issues with making webrtc2sip actually work. Webrtc2sip is now getting crashed intermittently during a call. I have seen this even when only one call is active in a queue. By the way, my setup involves a single server with Asterisk+Webrtc.

Below given is the webrtc2sip console log during crashing.

```
=============



*INFO: Request for peer at 14.140.176.234:54856 cannot be delivered
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Skipping redundant candidate address=199.115.112.66 and port=46268, fd=114, already_skipped(0)=no
*INFO: ICE reflexive candidates gathering ...1,0
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Skipping redundant candidate address=199.115.112.66 and port=46190, fd=111, already_skipped(0)=no
*INFO: ICE reflexive candidates gathering ...1,0
*INFO: Skipping redundant candidate address=199.115.112.66 and port=46269, fd=112, already_skipped(1)=no
*INFO: srflx_addr_count_added=0, srflx_addr_count_skipped=2
*INFO: Candidate: WvZ4zOZtT 1 udp 2130706431 199.115.112.66 46268 typ host
*INFO: Candidate: WvZ4zOZtT 2 udp 2130706430 199.115.112.66 46269 typ host
*INFO: State machine: ICE_fsm_GatheringReflexiveCandidates_2_GatheringReflexiveCandidatesDone_X_Success
*INFO: State machine: ICE_Any_2_GatheringCompleted_X_GatheringComplet
*INFO: ICE callback: Gathering candidates completed
*INFO: State machine: ICE_GatheringComplet_2_ConnChecking_X_ConnCheck
*INFO: ICE Pair: [WvZ4zOZtT 1 199.115.112.66 46268] -> [Hc7737042 1 199.115.112.66 17610]
*INFO: ICE Pair: [WvZ4zOZtT 1 199.115.112.66 46268] -> [Sc7737042 1 199.115.112.66 17610]
*INFO: ICE Pair: [WvZ4zOZtT 2 199.115.112.66 46269] -> [Hc7737042 2 199.115.112.66 17611]
*INFO: ICE Pair: [WvZ4zOZtT 2 199.115.112.66 46269] -> [Sc7737042 2 199.115.112.66 17612]
*INFO: Skipping redundant candidate address=199.115.112.66 and port=46191, fd=118, already_skipped(1)=no
*INFO: srflx_addr_count_added=0, srflx_addr_count_skipped=2
*INFO: Candidate: nwbkdDt4G 1 udp 2130706431 199.115.112.66 46190 typ host
*INFO: Candidate: nwbkdDt4G 2 udp 2130706430 199.115.112.66 46191 typ host
*INFO: State machine: ICE_fsm_GatheringReflexiveCandidates_2_GatheringReflexiveCandidatesDone_X_Success
*INFO: State machine: ICE_Any_2_GatheringCompleted_X_GatheringComplet
*INFO: ICE callback: Gathering candidates completed
*INFO: ICE: ignore processing SDP RO because version haven't changed
*INFO: is_ice_active=1,
is_ro_hold_resume_changed=0,
is_ro_provisional_final_matching=0,
is_ro_media_lines_changed=0,
is_ro_network_info_changed=0,
is_ro_loopback_address=0,
is_media_type_changed=0,
is_ro_codecs_changed=0

*INFO: tdav_consumer_audio_init()
**WARN: function: "tdav_session_audio_ctor()" 
file: "src/audio/tdav_session_audio.c" 
line: "794" 
MSG: No Audio denoiser found
*INFO: Create speekup jitter buffer
*INFO: Video 'zero-artifacts' option = no
*INFO: ICE enabled on RTP manager
*INFO: ICE enabled on RTP manager
*INFO: dtls.remote.setup=passive
*INFO: No codec matching for media type = 4
*INFO: Media session with media type = 'video' is a zombie
*INFO: State machine: s0000_Started_2_Ringing_X_iINVITE
*INFO: State machine: tsip_transac_ist_Proceeding_2_Proceeding_X_1xx
*INFO: 

SEND: SIP/2.0 180 Ringing
Via: SIP/2.0/UDP 199.115.112.66:5060;rport=5060;received=199.115.112.66;branch=z9hG4bK7ad2085b
From: <sip:agent5@agent5>;tag=as3d03cb14
To: <sip:agent5_voip.admin-ahead.com@199.115.112.66:10060;rtcweb-breaker=yes;transport=udp;ws-src-ip=14.140.176.234;ws-src-port=28560;ws-src-proto=wss>;tag=386222972
Contact: <sip:agent5_voip.admin-ahead.com@199.115.112.66:10060;transport=udp>
Call-ID: 3950314c4f14e9f0759fe3013c34bb26@agent5
CSeq: 102 INVITE
Content-Length: 0
Allow: ACK, BYE, CANCEL, INVITE, MESSAGE, NOTIFY, OPTIONS, PRACK, REFER, UPDATE




*INFO: State machine: ICE_GatheringComplet_2_ConnChecking_X_ConnCheck
*INFO: ICE Pair: [nwbkdDt4G 1 199.115.112.66 46190] -> [Hc7737042 1 199.115.112.66 17450]
*INFO: ICE Pair: [nwbkdDt4G 1 199.115.112.66 46190] -> [Sc7737042 1 199.115.112.66 17450]
*INFO: ICE Pair: [nwbkdDt4G 2 199.115.112.66 46191] -> [Hc7737042 2 199.115.112.66 17451]
*INFO: ICE Pair: [nwbkdDt4G 2 199.115.112.66 46191] -> [Sc7737042 2 199.115.112.66 17452]
***ERROR: function: "tsk_params_get_param_value()" 
file: "src/tsk_params.c" 
line: "219" 
MSG: Invalid parameter
***ERROR: function: "tsk_params_get_param_value()" 
file: "src/tsk_params.c" 
line: "219" 
MSG: Invalid parameter
*INFO: Negotiated codecs with the left leg = 96
*INFO: State machine: x0500_Current_2_Current_X_oINVITE
*INFO: tsk_timer_manager_start
*INFO: ICE CTX::run -- START
*INFO: State machine: ICE_Started_2_GatheringHostCandidates_X_GatherHostCandidates
*INFO: Timer manager run()::enter
*INFO: TIMER MANAGER -- START
*INFO: RTP/RTCP manager[Begin]: Trying to bind to random ports [199.115.112.66:54392]
*INFO: RTP/RTCP manager[End]: Trying to bind to random ports
*INFO: local ip address = 199.115.112.66
*INFO: State machine: ICE_GatheringHostCandidates_2_GatheringHostCandidatesDone_X_Success
*INFO: ICE using STUN server: stun.l.google.com:19302
*INFO: ICE callback: Gathering host candidates succeed
*INFO: State machine: ICE_GatheringHostCandidatesDone_2_GatheringReflexiveCandidates_X_GatherReflexiveCandidates
*INFO: ICE reflexive candidates gathering ...0,500000
*INFO: ICE context not active yet
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Skipping redundant candidate address=199.115.112.66 and port=54393, fd=117, already_skipped(0)=no
*INFO: ICE reflexive candidates gathering ...1,0
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Skipping redundant candidate address=199.115.112.66 and port=54392, fd=119, already_skipped(1)=no
*INFO: srflx_addr_count_added=0, srflx_addr_count_skipped=2
*INFO: Candidate: SI5Zel66a 1 udp 2130706431 199.115.112.66 54392 typ host
*INFO: Candidate: SI5Zel66a 2 udp 2130706430 199.115.112.66 54393 typ host
*INFO: State machine: ICE_fsm_GatheringReflexiveCandidates_2_GatheringReflexiveCandidatesDone_X_Success
*INFO: State machine: ICE_Any_2_GatheringCompleted_X_GatheringComplet
*INFO: ICE callback: Gathering candidates completed
*INFO: State machine: c0000_Started_2_Outgoing_X_oINVITE
*INFO: tdav_consumer_audio_init()
**WARN: function: "tdav_session_audio_ctor()" 
file: "src/audio/tdav_session_audio.c" 
line: "794" 
MSG: No Audio denoiser found
*INFO: Create speekup jitter buffer
*INFO: ICE enabled on RTP manager
*INFO: dtls.remote.setup=active
*INFO: Add call-id = 'a808aa98-acfb-9ec8-44d7-2e7ff9fbbc3c' to peer with local fd = 71
*** glibc detected *** ./webrtc2sip: double free or corruption (fasttop): 0x00007f49e0001340 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3e5f476166]
/usr/local/lib/libtinySAK.so.0(tsk_object_unref+0x42)[0x7f49e9d22522]
/usr/local/lib/libtinySAK.so.0(+0x86df)[0x7f49e9d206df]
/usr/local/lib/libtinySAK.so.0(tsk_object_delete+0x29)[0x7f49e9d22419]
/usr/local/lib/libtinySAK.so.0(tsk_object_unref+0x42)[0x7f49e9d22522]
/usr/local/lib/libtinySAK.so.0(tsk_list_remove_item_by_data+0x18)[0x7f49e9d20a98]
/usr/local/lib/libtinySAK.so.0(+0xf91f)[0x7f49e9d2791f]
/lib64/libpthread.so.0[0x3e5f8079d1]
/lib64/libc.so.6(clone+0x6d)[0x3e5f4e8b6d]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-004e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 28311572                           /opt/webrtc2sip/sbin/webrtc2sip
006e5000-006e9000 rw-p 000e5000 08:02 28311572                           /opt/webrtc2sip/sbin/webrtc2sip
01929000-0196e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
31fcc00000-31fcdb5000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 15471023                       /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
31fcdb5000-31fcfb5000 ---p 001b5000 08:02 15471023                       /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
31fcfb5000-31fcfd0000 r--p 001b5000 08:02 15471023                       /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
31fcfd0000-31fcfdc000 rw-p 001d0000 08:02 15471023                       /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.1.0.1e
31fcfdc000-31fcfe0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3464c00000-3464c03000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636102                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
3464c03000-3464e02000 ---p 00003000 08:02 5636102                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
3464e02000-3464e03000 r--p 00002000 08:02 5636102                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
3464e03000-3464e04000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 5636102                        /lib64/libcom_err.so.2.1
3465000000-34650db000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636103                        /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
34650db000-34652da000 ---p 000db000 08:02 5636103                        /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
34652da000-34652e4000 r--p 000da000 08:02 5636103                        /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
34652e4000-34652e6000 rw-p 000e4000 08:02 5636103                        /lib64/libkrb5.so.3.3
3465400000-3465441000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636110                        /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3465441000-3465641000 ---p 00041000 08:02 5636110                        /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3465641000-3465642000 r--p 00041000 08:02 5636110                        /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3465642000-3465644000 rw-p 00042000 08:02 5636110                        /lib64/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
3465800000-3465861000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 15473113                       /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
3465861000-3465a61000 ---p 00061000 08:02 15473113                       /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
3465a61000-3465a65000 r--p 00061000 08:02 15473113                       /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
3465a65000-3465a6c000 rw-p 00065000 08:02 15473113                       /usr/lib64/libssl.so.1.0.1e
3e5ec00000-3e5ec20000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636167                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3e5ee1f000-3e5ee20000 r--p 0001f000 08:02 5636167                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3e5ee20000-3e5ee21000 rw-p 00020000 08:02 5636167                        /lib64/ld-2.12.so
3e5ee21000-3e5ee22000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3e5f000000-3e5f002000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636219                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3e5f002000-3e5f202000 ---p 00002000 08:02 5636219                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3e5f202000-3e5f203000 r--p 00002000 08:02 5636219                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3e5f203000-3e5f204000 rw-p 00003000 08:02 5636219                        /lib64/libdl-2.12.so
3e5f400000-3e5f58b000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636168                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3e5f58b000-3e5f78a000 ---p 0018b000 08:02 5636168                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3e5f78a000-3e5f78e000 r--p 0018a000 08:02 5636168                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3e5f78e000-3e5f78f000 rw-p 0018e000 08:02 5636168                        /lib64/libc-2.12.so
3e5f78f000-3e5f794000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3e5f800000-3e5f817000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636317                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3e5f817000-3e5fa17000 ---p 00017000 08:02 5636317                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3e5fa17000-3e5fa18000 r--p 00017000 08:02 5636317                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3e5fa18000-3e5fa19000 rw-p 00018000 08:02 5636317                        /lib64/libpthread-2.12.so
3e5fa19000-3e5fa1d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3e5fc00000-3e5fce8000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 15469026                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
3e5fce8000-3e5fee8000 ---p 000e8000 08:02 15469026                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
3e5fee8000-3e5feef000 r--p 000e8000 08:02 15469026                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
3e5feef000-3e5fef1000 rw-p 000ef000 08:02 15469026                       /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.13
3e5fef1000-3e5ff06000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3e60000000-3e60083000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636505                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3e60083000-3e60282000 ---p 00083000 08:02 5636505                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3e60282000-3e60283000 r--p 00082000 08:02 5636505                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3e60283000-3e60284000 rw-p 00083000 08:02 5636505                        /lib64/libm-2.12.so
3e60400000-3e60415000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636504                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3e60415000-3e60614000 ---p 00015000 08:02 5636504                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3e60614000-3e60615000 r--p 00014000 08:02 5636504                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3e60615000-3e60616000 rw-p 00015000 08:02 5636504                        /lib64/libz.so.1.2.3
3e60c00000-3e60c1d000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636506                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3e60c1d000-3e60e1c000 ---p 0001d000 08:02 5636506                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3e60e1c000-3e60e1d000 r--p 0001c000 08:02 5636506                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3e60e1d000-3e60e1e000 rw-p 0001d000 08:02 5636506                        /lib64/libselinux.so.1
3e60e1e000-3e60e1f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
3e61000000-3e61016000 r-xp 00000000 08:02 5636220                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1
3e61016000-3e61215000 ---p 00016000 08:02 5636220                        /lib64/libgcc_s-4.4.7-20120601.so.1Aborted (core dumped)
=============
```

I have also noticed following error message unusual.

```
===========
*INFO: State machine: tsip_transac_nict_Completed_2_Terminated_X_timerK
*INFO: === NICT terminated ===
*INFO: *** NICT destroyed ***
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
*INFO: Not STUN message
*INFO: Audio producer not started yet
===============
```

Additional detials:

**I compiled webrtc2sip using their official technical guide.

> > webrtc2sip.org/technical-guide-1.0.pdf**

1st configuration:

```
/configure --with-ssl --with-srtp --with-speexdsp --with-ffmpeg=no --with-ilbc=no --with-opus=no --with-vpx=no --with-amr=no --with-yuv=no --with-speexdsp=no --with-gsm=no
```

. I tried to install all codecs specified in and did almost all. There were some codecs libyuv, ilbc, G729 which I could nt install. Webrtc2sip was successfully compiled first time excluding these codecs. But When I made a call it was being rejected most of the time. And service crashes often times. Sorry I dont have log for these now.

2nd time configuration

```
./configure --with-ssl --with-srtp --with-speexdsp --with-ffmpeg=no --with-vpx=no
```

This time I forcefully set all video codecs to 'no'. Otherwise video codecs are enabled default.(I think webrtc2sip is taking them as yes because it detects them installed in server).

Service was a little more stable than before. But it kept on crashing like for every other 2 calls. Above given core dump is produced by this configuration. I need some serious help on this.

```
Operating System
===========
[root@trial sbin]# cat /etc/issue
CentOS release 6.5 (Final)
Kernel \r on an \m

[root@trial sbin]# uname -r
2.6.32-431.11.2.el6.x86_64 (up to date)

Server has memory of 8gb and high h/w configuration.
[root@trial sbin]# lscpu
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                8
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-7
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    4
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               2128.000
BogoMIPS:              6385.58
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              8192K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7
```